# iPhone: how to create an empty bitmap in memory?

Tags: iphone

I need to create a empty bitmap (in memory) with known values of the width and height.
I'll use context of this bitmap to draw and then display  image on the MKOverlayVew.
Does anyone know the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Empty as in transparent?  Or "empty" as in filled with some background color (black, white, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do the trick. Originally from: [CGBitmapContextCreate on the iPhone/iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619224/cgbitmapcontextcreate-on-the-iphone-ipad)

```
      int width = 500;
      int height = 500;

      CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
      unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
      memset(rawData, 0, height * width * 4);

      NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
      NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
      NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
      CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
      // Do your thing and then release
      CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
      free(rawData);
      CGContextRelease(context);
```

I'm not sure if there's any difference with the code posted on that question, but the OP mentions memory issues and I never had any with this code I'm posting.

Comment: Thanks! This code really working. And working good. As a result, I got an increasing performance for my application approx to 100 times.

Comment: Once you've called CGBitmapContextCreate can you still modify pixel by writing inte rawData memory ?