# EXC_BAD_ACCESS When NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I'm developing an App that will update the UI every time a View "A" appears. I put the related code in the `ViewWillAppear` and this update will load some images in the document path of the app. Thus, I will load the related path in the section. And it works fine in the beginning, but if I navigate to another page (using `navigationController` to push page) and back to this page again several times, I will got an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);   // EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
NSString* docPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

.....
```

And if I temporarily change the code by hardcoding the path like:

```
NSString* docPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"****/****/***/Documents"];
```

then it will not crash.

I also tried to load the document path at `ViewDidLoad` and save the value to a variable where the property is `(nonatomic, retain)`.

And in the `ViewWillAppear`, I load the path like:

```
NSString* docPath = self.documentPath;
```

but it will also got an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at this line.

Before this line, I also tried to print the `self.documentPath`, and it will get the correct path string.

Comment: I suspect you are overwriting the memory somewhere.

Comment: So what was the problem, Ecroo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my this answer to see [how to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10982823/1449149) and then put up the error description here. 
That would help to answer your question.